# Given a absolute bit number (ex. 24), how do I set the appropriate bit in an array of words?

Tags: c#, arrays, bit

I have an array of 16-bit words and I want to calculate the bit to set in the proper word when just given the bit number.  For example, bit 24 sets the 8th bit in the 2nd word.

Comment: Not homework.  Taking over C++ legacy code from someone who is used to programming in Assembler.

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++ or Assembler. Simple Math.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use division to obtain the index in the array, and the remainder will be the bit number to set.

```
int N = 24;
int index = N / 16;
int bit = N % 16;

words[index] |= (1 << bit);
```

Comment: What about it? it does something, but not what you asked originally.

Comment: This sets the bit after the one you want unless n is zero indexed.  I would subtract 1 from n first.

Comment: Yes, I u9nderstand now.  Thank you!